# COMException when writing to Excel 2007 from Windows Forms

Tags: vb.net, excel-2007, com-interop, excel-interop

My Windows Forms app collects data from user input and mathematical calculation and outputs a set of results to an Excel spreadsheet.

Here's my code (for convenience, I've included only the code that seems relevant to the problem):

```
        Dim exc As New Excel.Application
        Dim book As Excel.Workbook
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

        book = exc.Workbooks.Add
        sheet = book.Sheets.Add

        Dim dc As System.Data.DataColumn
        Dim dr As System.Data.DataRow
        Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
        Dim rowIndex As Integer = 1

        exc.Cells(0, 0) = "Clearspan Cladding Sheet"
        exc.Cells(0, 1) = dtpDate.Value
        exc.Cells(0, 2) = "Job No. " & txtJob.Text
        exc.Cells(0, 3) = "By " & txtName.Text

        For Each dc In dtTotals.Columns
            colIndex = colIndex + 1
            exc.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
        Next
```

The error occurs when I try to to `Cell(0, 0)`. Below is the most detailed information I could get on the error. The `For...Next` loop works (as tested in previous debug sessions). As far as I can see, I'm doing exactly the same thing above it.

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.set__Default(Object RowIndex, Object ColumnIndex, Object Param)
   at Cladding.frmCladdingMain.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\logan.HO\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Clearspan\Cladding\frmCladdingMain.vb:line 240
```

As always, thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: AFAIK the cells collection is 1 based; (1,1) being A1

Comment: @Logan - Try sheet.Cells() Reference - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194567.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301982
The first row & col value is 1,1 ( i.e. A1 = cell(1,1) ).

Comment: yes.. it should be  exc.Cells(1, 1) = "Clearspan Cladding Sheet"
        exc.Cells(1, 2) = dtpDate.Value
        exc.Cells(1, 3) = "Job No. " & txtJob.Text
        exc.Cells(1, 4) = "By " & txtName.Text

Comment: Using the collection as 1-based got rid of the error, but the info that's going in there isn't being written to the spreadsheet

Comment: use  exc.Cells(1, colIndex).value = dc.ColumnName. & increase the column index after this statement.